# Нарисовать черту любыми средствами

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Необходимо "отрисовать" такую черту, как в примерах во вложении. Фишка в том, что ширина ее должна меняться в зависимости от длины слова/словосочетания, но при этом высота (толщина линии) должна оставаться везде одинаковой. И да - линия имеет изгиб, так что простые средства (вывести линию стилями и добавить rotate) не подойдут. Устроит любой вариант реализации: чистый css, манипуляции с svg, скрипты.
SVG-код:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="208px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 208 26" enable-background="new 0 0 208 26" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="none" stroke="#EE4036" stroke-width="9" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M5,21
    c8.013-1.548,36.453-5.574,86.106-9.29C140.759,7.994,186.391,5.688,203,5"/>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Подчёркивание всегда в последней строчке абзаца? Если нет, то как должно выглядеть подчёркивание между строк?

Comment: Если это имеет значение, то подчеркивание может быть в любой части текста. Если наложится на строку ниже - не страшно.

Comment: D3.js
не только для рисования линий,но и работает на всех браузерах

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если немного упростить кривую Безье, убрав лишнюю опорную точку, то логика её построения становится более наглядной и можно создавать svg на лету:

```js
let underlined = document.querySelectorAll('.underline');
let strokeWidth = 8;
let strokeColor = 'rgb(238,64,54)';


underlined.forEach(function(item) {
  let w = item.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let x0 = strokeWidth/2;
  let x1 = w * 0.3;
  let x2 = w * 0.7;
  let x3 = w - strokeWidth/2;
  let d = 'M' + x0 + ',15' + 'C' + x1 + ',10,' + x2 + ',5,' + x3 + ',8';
  
  let bg = 'url(\'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 '
  + w + ' 26" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="none" stroke="' 
  + strokeColor + '" stroke-width="'
  + strokeWidth +'" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="'
  + d + '"/></svg>\')';
  
  item.style.backgroundImage = bg;
});
```

```css
div { font-size:18px; }  
.underline {
  background-size:100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:left bottom;
  padding-bottom:1.2em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="underline">Оченьдлинноеслово</span> и <span class="underline">короткое</span></div>
```

Comment: Вот отличное решение! И сама пришла к такому же, только менее изящно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 9):

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span')

function drawLine(el, txt) {
const tagName = 'qqqq'
const str = el.innerHTML
const reg = new RegExp(txt, 'gi')
const newStr = str.replaceAll(reg, `<${tagName}>${txt}</${tagName}>`)
el.innerHTML = newStr
const marks = el.querySelectorAll(tagName)
const elStyles = el.getBoundingClientRect()
marks.forEach(el => {
    const mark = el.getBoundingClientRect()
    const coords = {
        top: mark.bottom - 5,
        left: mark.x - elStyles.x + 5,
        right: mark.right,
        width: mark.width + 10,
    }
    addLine(el, coords)
})
}

function addLine(el, coords) {
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = coords.width
canvas.height = '10'
delete coords.width
Object.keys(coords).forEach(key => coords[key] += 'px')
ctx.beginPath();
const roundWidth = 3
ctx.lineWidth = roundWidth
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.lineCap = 'round'
ctx.moveTo(roundWidth, canvas.height - roundWidth);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(
    canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 2, 
    canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 4, 
    canvas.width - roundWidth, roundWidth
    );
ctx.stroke();
el.appendChild(canvas)
canvas.style.display = 'block'
canvas.style.position = 'absolute'
Object.assign(canvas.style, coords)
}

drawLine(span, 'sit')
drawLine(span, 'blanditiis')
```

```css
span {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam maiores  blanditiis explicabo quod impedit sit amet consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam maiores  blanditiis explicaboLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam maiores  blanditiis explicabo </span>
```

Comment: Прикольно, но "толщина линии должна быть постоянной при переменной длине". Думаю, раз всё равно JS, то нужно на ходу SVG генерить с правильными координатами.

Comment: @UModeL переделал. Но есть проблема с текстом из двух слов, при их переносе. Лень над ней думать)

Comment: @Дмытрык Как вариант, запретить переносить подчеркнутое: `qqqq {white-space:nowrap}`

Comment: @Дмытрык, спасибо! Ваш вариант самый рабочий. Генереный канвас пока не оч похож на линию из макета, но работаю над этим.

Comment: Как по мне, так идеально ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Это ответ **@Alexandr** с тем отличием, что для фона псевдоэлемента все-таки используется оригинальный SVG. Чтобы толщина линии оставалась постоянной, добавляем в элемент svg атрибут `preserveAspectRatio="none"`:

```css
span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="408px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 208 26" enable-background="new 0 0 208 26" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="none" stroke="%23EE4036" stroke-width="9" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M5,21 c8.013-1.548,36.453-5.574,86.106-9.29C140.759,7.994,186.391,5.688,203,5"/></svg>');
  left: 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  bottom: -20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Оченьдлинноеслово</span> и <span>короткое</span></div>
```

Comment: не нашел как это сделать)

Answer (score 3):

Задайте подчеркивание через background к :after

```css
span::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/YDHcpCp/line.png');
  left:0;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
bottom:-20px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
span{
position:relative;

}
```

```html
<div><span>Оченьдлинноеслово</span> и <span>короткое</span></div>
```

Comment: Это очевидное решение не подходит: отстутствуют скругления концов линии. И в том числе: отображается только часть черты, причем, из середины, где изгиб минимален. Даже если делать background-position: 0 0, то теряем скругление справа.

Comment: И чтобы не трогать уже использованные решения уточню: можно, конечно, сделать правую часть вторым псевдоэлементом с background-position: right, но по центру эти элементы не состыкуются. Нужно или считать скриптом это отклонение или искать менее зверское решение.

Comment: @Ольга поправил, концы видно, толщина одинаковая

Comment: @Alexandr, так не считается, концы перестают быть круглыми при деформации картинки :)

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirov без деформации ее надо каждый раз отрисовывать под каждое слово отдельно

Comment: Если бы устраивали деформации, то местный разум и не понадобился ((